# How to interrogate queued jobs on a Laravel queue?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-queue

How can I efficiently interrogate jobs on a Laravel queue?

For example, my RosterEmployee job has an Employee property.  I have a lot of these jobs queued.  Later, I need to terminate a batch of Employees, and in doing so I want to identify any queued jobs that should be deleted.  (There is no point in Rostering an employee if they are about to be terminated).

To do this, I need to identify jobs where the EmployeeId is the same as an employee who is in the termination batch and delete the jobs.

(I realize that in the real world, there would be better ways to accomplish this Employee termination logic, however, I have contrived the example to demonstrate my need - efficiently interrogating jobs on a Laravel queue.)

Comment: Have you read about cancelling batches in queue,https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#inspecting-batches

Comment: Thanks Manuel, but that's not what I am looking for.

Comment: When you mean the job with the same employee, do you mean the employee gets added twice when it should be unique?